# the word with same alphabet repeating more than 3 times in R

Tags: r

In R, how do i replace the word with same alphabet repeating 3 or more times by NA?

For example `cakkkkkkkkkkkkkkkeeeeeee` becomes `NA`. Another example would be `zzzzzzzzz` becomes `NA`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `str_detect`

```
library(stringr)
ifelse(str_detect(str1, "([a-z])\\1{2,}"), NA, str1)
#[1] NA         NA         "abcd"     "aabbcbbd" NA
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("cakkkkkkkkkkkkkkkeeeeeee", "zzzzzzzzz", "abcd", "aabbcbbd",  "aaabbcbbd")
```

Comment: Warning: not sure if it's the case inside `stringi` (which `stringr` uses), but the TRE implementation of `{m,}` regexes is buggy: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=14408

Comment: @Hugh, at the bottom of that page it says it was fixed

Comment: You're right: it seems ok for `{m,}`, though expressions like `grepl("ab{,2}c", "abbbc")` are still wrong in `R 3.4.3`.

Answer (score 3):

Another way similar to akrun would be to use [`grepl`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html):

```
library(stringr)
ifelse(grepl("([a-zA-Z])\\1{2,}", str1), NA, str1)
```

Comment: also, since they want to change those elements, they could use things like `is.na(str1) <- grepl("([A-Za-z])\\1{2,}", str1)` of `str1[grepl("([A-Za-z])\\1{2,}", str1)] <- NA`

Comment: Why do you load stringr?